# subdomain to other server cPanel addon domain

Tags: dns, domain, cpanel

I want to redirect **nuki**.example.ch to one of my other servers. I create a A record and know I see that the url realy redirect to my target server. 
But I can't configure the target server that he accept and glue the domain to a folder.

When I try to add a addon domain in Cpanel I always get the error:

> (XID tq3t6y) Sorry, the domain is already pointed to an IP address
>   that does not appear to use DNS servers associated with this server.
>   Please transfer the domain to this servers nameservers or have your
>   administrator add one of its nameservers to /etc/ips.remotedns and
>   make the proper A entries on that remote nameserver.

Any ideas?

PS: I also ask the provider, but he doesent want to help. .-.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to redirect *nuki.example.ch* to one of my other servers.

Assuming that this is registered with a normal registrar and your target is CPanel, you likely have one of two options:

1. Switch your *example.ch* nameservers to the nameservers of your CPanel provider (probably not ideal if you want to use only the sub-domain).
2. Redirect *nuki.example.ch* to another domain that your CPanel target does service.

As a third option, you could redirect to hosting that does not use CPanel as a target (i.e. A VPS or similar where you set up the machine to run Apache, etc. like a traditional physical server).